# display html in textview with highlighted sentence/syntax

Tags: android, html, fonts, colors, textview

Hi I am beginner in android. but I have written some sentence and C code which is formatted in HTML using some style like font-color. I tried to display in TextView, it works fine but font color displayed only in black color.
help me from this problem by writing an example. thank you in advanced.

> code

```
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_display);
 String s = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "  <meta content=\"text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\"\n" +
                " http-equiv=\"content-type\">\n" +
                "  <title></title>\n" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span\n" +
                " style=\"color: rgb(0, 176, 80);\" lang=\"EN-US\">This is\n" +
                "C program\n" +
                "displaying in android TextView :-<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">#include&lt;<span\n" +
                " style=\"color: rgb(84, 141, 212);\">stdio.h</span>&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">#include&lt;<span\n" +
                " style=\"color: rgb(84, 141, 212);\">conio.h</span>&gt;<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">Void\n" +
                "main()<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">{<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\"><span\n" +
                " style=\"\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n" +
                "</span>Printf(&ldquo;<span\n" +
                " style=\"color: rgb(84, 141, 212);\">Hello android..!!</span>&rdquo;)<span\n" +
                " style=\"color: red;\">;</span><o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\"><span\n" +
                " style=\"\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n" +
                "</span>getch()<span style=\"color: red;\">;</span><o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span lang=\"EN-US\">}<o:p></o:p></span></p>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

I have created this html using NVU.

I really want to display in textview is given below:

```
This is C program displaying in android TextView :-//font color green

    #include<stdio.h> //stdio.h font color blue
    #include<conio.h> //conio.h font color blue
    Void main()
    {
        Printf(“Hello android..!!”);//hello android font color blue
        getch();//semi colon font color red
    }
```

Comment: What u have tried post your code !! so every one helps u :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "<font color='black'>Google</font><font color='red'>Android</font>";
    tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

use webView it perfect loading data

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.. with this code my activity start and automatically closed it without any text displayed

Comment: use web view Insted Textview it's work perfect in webView i Checked your code but i have no ideat y not its working in textView

Comment: yeah I have already done it.. it works well in adroid webview.. In my case I want to display in Textview. Is there any way to display it in TextView